# trying to put 3 carousels on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been looking around for this yet am unable to find info on how to do it.
I have a website and I am trying to implement 3 different j carousels on the page.

Problem is, when I click on the next button they all move.
I've changed the button names and applied the changes into the css and jquery but it doesnt seem to work.
Any one know how to do this?

```js
 $(function(){
  $(".carousel").jCarouselLite({
   btnNext: ".next",
   btnPrev: ".prev",
   visible: 5,
   speed: 1000,
  })
 })
```

```css
#carousel img{height:200px;width:200px;padding:5px; margin: 0 5px; border: 5px solid #CCC; }
.next {float:right;background:#069;border:0px;}
.prev {float:left;background:#069;border:0px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>slider-carousel</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/js/jcarousel.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="carousel">
 
    <div class="carousel">

  <ul>
         <li><img src="assets/adds/add1.png" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="assets/adds/add2.png" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="assets/adds/add3.png" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="assets/adds/add4.png" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="assets/adds/add5.png" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="assets/adds/add6.png" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="assets/adds/add1.png" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="assets/adds/add2.png" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="assets/adds/add3.png" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="assets/adds/add4.png" alt="" /></li>
        </ul>
        <button class="prev">Back</button><button class="next">Next</button>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Ive only put one carousel as an example and there are external jquery files that come from google and the javascript website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the plugin function twice and identify the button differently (maybe you should use ids on it).

```
$(function(){
    $(".carousel1").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: ".next",
        btnPrev: ".prev",
        visible: 5,
        speed: 1000,
    });
    $(".carousel2").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: ".next2",
        btnPrev: ".prev2",
        visible: 5,
        speed: 1000,
    })        
})
```

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c71fkj15/

Hope it helps.

ps: Are you sure you really need to use 3 carousels on the same page? (One is already too much imo :p) just sayin :)

Comment: Hey Guillaume, Thank you for that as it worked well.
I have 4 different carousels running where users can relate to different things, that is why I have 3 different carousels.Now all I need to do is figure out how to implement a popup bobble on hover.
You have any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Guillaume, yes.
Ill explain to you what I am doing.
I am building a website in html5 CSS3. Once I have it all functioning correctly, Im going to put it all into codeigniter.
So my current aim is to have it all built in HTML5 and CSS3.
But the example of what you have shown me is what I am looking to implement.
I tried to do it and it stuffs up my carousel.